# ajax live search not showing data on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im building a live search function for my site and i have run into an issue. the below script works fine for getting results from my database to the page when i type in the input field however on page load nothing shows until i search the box

my ideal solution loads the content on the page via ajax then i can narrow down the results with the search field

how can this be done

this my search box

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' onkeyup='showResult(this.value)'>
```

this is how the results show on the page from the ajax request

```
<table class='table table-togglable table-hover'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-toggle='true'>SMS ID</th>
        <th data-hide='phone'>Time Stamp</th>
        <th data-hide='phone,tablet'>Mobile Number</th>
        <th data-hide='phone,tablet'>Message</th>
        <th data-hide='phone'>Message Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody  id='records_table'>
</tbody>
</table>
```

this is the ajax script

```
<script>
function showResult(str) {  
$.ajax({
    url: "getjson.php?search="+str, 
    type: "GET",    
    dataType:"json",   
    success: function (response) 
    {
      var trHTML = '';
      $.each(response, function (key,value) {
         trHTML += 
            '<tr><td>' + value.ID + 
            '</td><td>' + value.Timestamp + 
            '</td><td>' + value.Number + 
            '</td><td>' + value.Message + 
            '</td><td>' + value.Status + 
            '</td></tr>';     
      });
        $('#records_table').html(trHTML);
    }   
});     
}
</script>
```

Comment: nothing shows in the console as the script works however i have to type something before the results are loaded

Comment: You want that after the page load the results to appear again by themselves and the query to remain inside the box?

Comment: i would like on page load for it to load all rows in the database then when i  enter something in the search box it narrow down those results

Comment: So your search will "search" on the html, not the database. JavaScript will be the solution. but if you have 1k+ rows that will be really messy.

Comment: i would really like to do this with jquery -  currently i have tested the above and its working fine if i search 1 letter and remove the letter it will display all the results. i just need to be display them all on page load aswell as when i enter letters it removed whats in the dom and put my searched terms which it does i just cant get it to load a blank search on page load

Comment: allow php to return ALL the values when the ?search query is empty, then use jquery; $(document).ready(function(){ showResults("")}); to load all the results on page load

Comment: wow perfect. thank you that works